# How to get facebook page unlike_count using FQL QUERY

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I have created a page on facebook and get their details using fql query. Here I mentioned the fql query

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count,  comment_count, total_count, comments_fbid, click_count  FROM link_stat WHERE url = 'https://www.facebook.com/AchchaYenbadhuMadamaiyada'
```

Raw datas are as follows:

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [url] => https://www.facebook.com/AchchaYenbadhuMadamaiyada
            [normalized_url] => https://www.facebook.com/AchchaYenbadhuMadamaiyada
            [share_count] => 0
            [like_count] => 41
            [comment_count] => 0
            [total_count] => 41
            [comments_fbid] => 
            [click_count] => 0
        )

)
```

How to get **unlike_count** details using **fql** query or any other possible ways. If anyone knows it please share your thoughts.

Comment: FQL is deprecated. Unlikes are only available via insights, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights

Comment: There is no such thing a `unlike_count`...

Comment: @Tobi, not true, as CBroe mentioned correctly, there is a metric `page_fan_removes` available through the Insights API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/insights#page_users)

Comment: @BjörnKaiser As I wrote, there is NO metric called `unlike_count`. Not more not less.